# Spring MVC urls without .something extension

Tags: spring-mvc, url-rewriting

First off, if this is a duplicate, I apologize.  I did quite a bit of searching but couldn't find much and I suspect I wasn't using the right terms...

I'm building a site with Spring MVC and using the annotation-driven configuration.  What I'd like to do is have urls that do not have any extension at the end (.html, .do, etc).  So they would look like `http://www.mysite.com/account/create` which I know is something that is traditionally accomplished using `mod_rewrite` on Apache or using files without extensions.  It seems as though it could be done without using a rewrite engine (I know about the urlrewritefilter project) as Spring has support for pulling parameters out of the request string (See section 15.3.2.1 of [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)) and the pet store example doesn't appear to have extensions at the end of its urls.

However, it seems as though whenever I attempt to forward all requests to the dispatcher servlet (my thinking for how to negate the need for something like `*.htm`), I run into trouble...I'm able to get it work (using XML configuration, I recently switched to annotation configuration) using just a standard "*.htm" for all of the pages.

My controller code looks like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get() {

        ...

    }
```

And my web.xml looks like

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Am I missing something here? Is this possible without using a rewrite engine?

I should note, the above configuration doesn't work.  It always returns a `404` error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using URL patterns such as `/*` is generally a bad idea, since the container will forward everything to the `DispatcherServlet`, including internal requests for JSPs. So when your controller returns the JSP name in the `ModelAndView`, it will be fed back into the `DispatcherServlet` again, giving you the 404.

You either need to retain the file extension in your paths, or you need a prefix of some kind to allow you to distinguish requestd for the `DispstcherServlet` from requests for JSPs.

Comment: That is an excellent point and one I hadn't thought of.  Should something like `/app/*` work?

Comment: That did it, thanks!  For what it's worth, I also had my `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in the servlet xml file rather than in the context configuration file...